# Nested NSDictionary Description Escape Character Problems

Tags: objective-c, escaping, nested, nsdictionary

I am trying to print out an objectified JSON structure that I am saving in multiple dictionaries in a hierarchy. I would like to do this through NSObject's `description` method so that each nested dictionary's description method gets called returning its value as well.

**Desired Result**

```
        //First Hierarchal Level
                //Second Hierarchal Level
                        //Third Hierarchal Level
People = 
(
    {
        Name = Person 1
        Gender = Male
        Addresses =
        (   
            {
                Address Name = Home Address
                Street = 123 Street St.
                City = NewCity
                State = AZ
                Zip = 12345
                Country = USA
             }
        )
        Cars = 
        (   
            {
                Make = Ford
                Model = NewFord
                Insured Drivers = 
                (
                    {
                        Name = Person 1
                    },
                    {
                        Name = Person 2
                    }
                )
            }
        )   
    }
)

//NOTE: Sample untested nested structure
```

However, I have been running into an issue that the return string for each nested dictionary is getting escaped once for each level of the hierarchy that the return string gets passed through.

**Actual Result**

```
People = \n (\n {\n Name = Person 1\\\n Gender = Male\\\n Addresses =\\\n ( \\\n {\\\n Address Name = Home Address\\\n Street = 123 Street St.\\\n City = NewCity\\\n State = AZ\\\n Zip = 12345\\\n Country = USA\\\n }\\\n )\\\n Cars = \\\n ( \\\n {\\\\\\\n Make = Ford\\\\\\\n Model = NewFord\\\\\\\n Insured Drivers = \\\\\\\n (\\\\\\\n {\\\\\\\\\\\\\n Name = Person 1\\\\\\\\\\\\\n },\\\\\\\\\\\\\n {\\\\\\\\\\\\\n Name = Person 2\\\\\\\\\\\\\n }\\\\\\\n )\\\\\\\n }\\\n ) \n }\n )
```

I have read that this has to do with how description adds these escape characters due to it using something like a syslog utility, however I believe the functionality that I desire is available due to how NSArray describes its contents in a similar way to the way in which I would like to. I have tried iterating through the result string and parsing out the escape characters but so far the best result that I have come up with is a non-hierarchical list of all the properties in all dictionaries.

**Best Attempt**

```
People = 
(
{
Name = Person 1
Gender = Male
Addresses =
( 
{
Address Name = Home Address
Street = 123 Street St.
City = NewCity
State = AZ
Zip = 12345
Country = USA
}
)
Cars = 
( 
{
Make = Ford
Model = NewFord
Insured Drivers = 
(
{
Name = Person 1
},
{
Name = Person 2
}
)
}
) 
}
)
```

I was wondering if anyone else has come across this problem and how they overcame it.

Any and all suggestions welcome. 
Thanks for looking.

UPDATE 1:
As per the advice in the comments, I have tried parsing my dictionary objects to JSON strings for printing using the following NSDictionary category method:

```
-(NSString*)JSONDescription
{
    NSError *error;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString* json = nil;

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: NSDictionary JSONDescription encountered error \"%@\"", error);
    } else {
        json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return json;
}
```

Then, at each level of of my hierarchy, I am calling my dictionary object's `JSONDescription` in each `description` method. However, it does not appear that the nested object's `description` method is being called. This is causing the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Address)'
```

**Example Implementation**

```
#import "Person.h"

#define NAME @"Name"
#define GENDER @"Gender"
#define ADDRESSES @"Addresses"
#define CARS @"Cars"

@implementation Person

-(NSDictionary*)toDictionary{
    return @{ NAME: self.name,
              GENDER: self.gender,
              ADDRESSES: self.addresses,
              CARS: self.cars};
}

-(NSString*)description{
    return self.toDictionary.JSONDescription;
}

@end


#import "Address.h"

#define ADDRESS_NAME @"Address Name"
#define STREET @"Street"
#define CITY @"City"
#define STATE @"State"
#define ZIP @"Zip"
#define COUNTRY @"Country"

@implementation Address

-(NSDictionary*)toDictionary{
    return @{ ADDRESS_NAME: self.addressName,
              STREET: self.street,
              CITY: self.city,
              STATE: self.state,
              ZIP: self.zip,
              COUNTRY: self.country};
}

-(NSString*)description{
    return self.toDictionary.JSONDescription;
}

@end


#import "Car.h"

#define MAKE @"Make"
#define MODEL @"Model"
#define INSURED_DRIVERS @"Insured Drivers"

@implementation Car

-(NSDictionary*)toDictionary{
    return @{ MAKE: self.make,
              MODEL: self.model,
              INSURED_DRIVERS: self.drivers};
}

-(NSString*)description{
    return self.toDictionary.JSONDescription;
}

@end


#import "Driver.h"

#define NAME @"Name"

@implementation Car

-(NSDictionary*)toDictionary{
    return @{ NAME: self.name};
}

-(NSString*)description{
    return self.toDictionary.JSONDescription;
}

@end
```

Comment: I am slightly confused because you sometimes show "key = value" (as in a dictionary) and sometimes "key : value" (as in JSON) in your examples. Which one do you want in the output? - And can you show your code that produced the "best attempt"?

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. I have fixed the example. While of course I would want them to be consistant, either style will work for the desired output as t. I am more concerned with the indentation and printing the newlines than I am concerned if it uses equals or colons.

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have the code the produced my best attempt but it consisted of nothing more than a few different [myDescriptionString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\"] that removed all of the escaped characters that were added. I could not figure out how to properly add back in the indentation.

Comment: What about converting (back) to JSON with the NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following method might not be the most elegant, but it seems to produce the desired output:

```
@interface NSObject (MyPrettyPrint)
- (NSString *)prettyPrint;
@end

// === ADDED CODE FOR CUSTOM OBJECTS (1) ===
@protocol ObjectToDictionary <NSObject>
-(NSDictionary *)toDictionary;
@end
// === END OF ADDED CODE (1) ===

@implementation NSObject (MyPrettyPrint)

- (NSString *)prettyPrint
{
    BOOL isColl;
    return [self prettyPrintAtLevel:0 isCollection:&isColl];
}

- (NSString *)prettyPrintAtLevel:(int)level isCollection:(BOOL *)isCollection;
{

// === ADDED CODE FOR CUSTOM OBJECTS (2) ===
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(toDictionary)]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [(id <ObjectToDictionary>)self toDictionary];
        return [dict prettyPrintAtLevel:level isCollection:isCollection];
    }
// === END OF ADDED CODE (2) ===

    NSString *padding = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:level withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableString *desc = [NSMutableString string];

    if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSArray *array = (NSArray *)self;
        NSUInteger cnt = [array count];
        [desc appendFormat:@"%@(\n", padding];
        for (id elem in array) {
            BOOL isColl;
            NSString *s = [elem prettyPrintAtLevel:(level+3) isCollection:&isColl];
            if (isColl) {
                [desc appendFormat:@"%@", s];
            } else {
                [desc appendFormat:@"%@   %@", padding, s];
            }
            if (--cnt > 0)
                [desc appendString:@","];
            [desc appendString:@"\n"];
        }
        [desc appendFormat:@"%@)", padding ];
        *isCollection = YES;

    } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)self;
        [desc appendFormat:@"%@{\n", padding];
        for (id key in dict) {
            BOOL isColl;
            id value = dict[key];
            NSString *s = [value prettyPrintAtLevel:(level+3) isCollection:&isColl];
            if (isColl) {
                [desc appendFormat:@"   %@%@ =\n%@\n", padding, key, s];
            } else {
                [desc appendFormat:@"   %@%@ = %@\n", padding, key, s];
            }
        }
        [desc appendFormat:@"%@}", padding ];
        *isCollection = YES;

    } else {
        [desc appendFormat:@"%@", self];
        *isCollection = NO;
    }

    return desc;
}
```

*Example:*

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"People": @[
    @{
        @"Name": @"Person 1",
        @"Gender": @"Male",
        @"Addresses": @[
            @{
                @"Address Name": @"Home Address",
                @"Street": @"123 Street St.",
                @"Zip": @12345
            },
        ],
        @"Cars": @[
           @{
                @"Make": @"Ford",
                @"Model": @"NewFord",
                @"Insured Drivers": @[
                    @{@"Name": @"Person 1"},
                    @{@"Name": @"Person 2"},
                ]
            },
        ],
   },

]};

NSLog(@"People =\n%@", [dict[@"People"] prettyPrint]);
```

*Output:*

```
People =
(
   {
      Name = Person 1
      Gender = Male
      Cars =
      (
         {
            Model = NewFord
            Make = Ford
            Insured Drivers =
            (
               {
                  Name = Person 1
               },
               {
                  Name = Person 2
               }
            )
         }
      )
      Addresses =
      (
         {
            Zip = 12345
            Address Name = Home Address
            Street = 123 Street St.
         }
      )
   }
)
```

Comment: This is the very close to the solution that I have currently. However, when applied to my example with each object creating the dictionary value of itself as the description, every line is at the first level of indentation. This puts the output nearly identical to the answer I have listed as my best attempt.  Thanks for your response, I feel like we are getting much closer!

Comment: Each layer of the object hierarchy needs to construct a dictionary representation of itself for printing. Otherwise the data parsed from my JSON is stored in properties on these objects. In this format, the object is not easily printable. My attempt to make these objects easily printable included caching these values into a dictionary and printing the dictionary to the description. Please let me know if you aware of a better way to do this.

Comment: @Krejko: I did not see before that you have custom objects `Car`, `Address` etc. My method was meant to be applied to the complete dictionary that you get from NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Ah yes. It is this nesting that I believe is what makes this quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: @Krejko: Yes. For a nested dictionary/array structure my method solves that by passing the "padding" parameter down and the "isCollection" parameter up. Caching the description seems difficult to me due to the indentation. Suggestions: 1) Convert your complete object hierarchy to a pure nested dictionary/array structure and then apply my method (or the JSON pretty print) to that. 2) Try to apply the idea of my functions to your classes. - But I am giving up at the moment!

Comment: Ok. I will certainly look into both of those solutions. @Martin R Thank you so much for sharing your thoughts on this problem with me.

Comment: @Krejko: I think I have found a way how you can use my `prettyPrint` method with your custom objects, using your `toDictionary` method. See "=== ADDED CODE FOR CUSTOM OBJECTS ===" in my edited answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: This looks like it should work. I will give it a try and let you know the results. Thanks once again!!!

Comment: Your solution worked wonderfully. It only pretty prints when  I explicitly call 'prettyPrinter' function on each non-custom object (like NSArray*) but for custom objects I can set self.prettyPrint as the return value for its description method and it works every time. I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Krejko: You are welcome. I have also read your new question, and according to the current documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4), overriding a method in a category is undefined behaviour.